# simple if else statement unit conversion

Tags: ruby, if-statement

i wrote this code but it is not working. I would really appreciate help:

```
puts "Welcome to my unit conversion calculator. This calculator can convert
    between Centimeters and Inches. If you could like to convert Centimeters to Inches,    
    write: in. If you would like to convert Inches to centimeters, write: cm."

unit = gets

puts " how many of your unit would you like to convert"

a = 0.39370079

b = 2.54

unit_number = gets.to_f

if unit = cm

    (unit_number * a)

else unit = in

    (unit_number * b)
end
```

Comment: Which programing language you are using and can you show me Types of variables

Comment: `elsif` instead of `else` because of second condition `unit = in`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the if statement isn't doing quite what you want. To check for equality, use `==`. `=` is assignment

```
if unit == cm
```

but you really want `'cm'`, since it is a string. You need to wrap it in quotes to let the runtime know you mean a string:

```
if unit == 'cm'
```

and finally, you need to output back to the user what the conversion was

```
puts unit_number * a
```

or even better

```
result = unit_number * a
puts "converting #{unit_number} to #{unit} is #{result}"
```

Comment: thanks. i made the changes but it always multiplies the unit_number by  a ( which is 2.54) whether i put cm or in.

Comment: sorry i meant variable b

Comment: my code looks like this:puts "Welcome to my unit conversion calculator. This calculator can convert
between Centimeters and Inches. If you could like to convert Centimeters to Inches, write: in. If you would like to convert Inches to centimeters, write: cm."

unit = gets

puts " how many of your unit would you like to convert"
unit_number = gets.to_f

a = 0.39370079
b = 2.54

if unit == 'in'
        puts "your conversion is: #{ (unit_number * a)}"
else unit == 'cm'
        puts "your conversion is: #{ (unit_number * b)}"
end